# Is there a way to create a new file and insert text into this file all with bash?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I need to change and create several configuration files for some kiosks at work, is there a way to do this with a single bash script? I've heard about SED but the documentation is confusing, could someone give an example?

Comment: The generic answer is *yes*: `echo 'text into this file' > 'a new file'`. I don't see how this helps change configuration files though.  Maybe you want to be more specific about the changes you need to make to certain files?

Comment: I'm very new to bash, do I need to specify the file directory in 'a new file'?

Comment: By default `a new file` will be in the current working directory.  You can specify another directory in the manner that you'd expect: `> 'subdir/a new file'` or `> '../a new file'` or `> /root/a new file`.

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly it is that you need to change in these configuration files? If all you intend to do is replace word 'abc' with 'xyz', `sed` might be the perfect tool for you. If not, maybe some other tool can be suggested based on your requirement.

Comment: Are you editing, creating, or appending files?  If creating then `>` will redirect to a new file (or overwrite an existing one).  If you want to append a file then `>>` adds lines to the end of a file. If you want to modify then your friends will be the redirections as above PLUS `cat`, `sed`, `cut`, and `grep`. The above redirections are for standard output.  If you are doing more advanced tasks you will need different redirections.

Answer (score 2):

You are not clear: Are you editing old files, or creating entirely new ones?

New ones can be created in this style with a single bash script:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF >firstfile
1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
EOF

cat <<EOF >secondfile
2. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
EOF

echo Done.

$ chmod 755 script.sh 

$ ./script.sh 
Done.

$ for f in *file ; do echo -e "\n--- $f ---" ; cat $f ; done

--- firstfile ---
1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

--- secondfile ---
2. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

$
```

To change simple things in already existing files:

```
$ tail -n 2 dead.letter 
With kind regards,
Hannu

$ sed -i -re 's/ kind/ very best/' dead.letter

$ tail -n 2 dead.letter 
With very best regards,
Hannu

$
```

Comment: Sorry, never used this site before. I'm actually doing both. Some of the files already exist, and some I need to create entirely new. I think I have it figured out from your example though, thanks!

Comment: General scripting can be learnt from the Bash guides at http://www.tldp.org/guides.html

Comment: Changing files... ^- added.